# Unsure why this query is inserting duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Customers` which has the PK `CustomerID` and two date fields `TransDate` and `UpdatedDate`.

I have another table `PaymentPlan` which has three date fields: `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `UpdatedDate`.

I need to find all `Customer` records that meet the following criteria and then insert them into another table.

- `TransDate` is not `null` and falls between any one `PaymentPlan` record's `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
- `TransDate` is `null` and `UpdatedOn` falls between any one `PaymentPlan` record's `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
- Regardless of whether or not `TransDate` is `null`, the `UpdatedOn` value of `Customers` must be older than the `UpdatedOn` of `PaymentPlan`.

The problem I'm having is that my query is returning duplicate `CustomerID` values.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Find_Customers_For_ReCalc
    @aDaysBack int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @aDaysBack = @aDaysBack * -1; -- Since we're looking "back" in time, we want the negative value of the number passed to the procedure

    INSERT INTO ReCalc (CustomerID, InsertedOn, RecordStatus, ProcessedOn)
    SELECT CustomerID, GETDATE() As InsertedOn, 0 As RecordStatus, null As ProcessedOn
    FROM Customers
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT P.Code, P.StartDate, P.EndDate, P.UpdatedOn
        FROM PaymentPlan P 
        WHERE P.UpdatedOn >= DATEADD(day, @aDaysBack, GETDATE()) AND DeletedOn IS NULL
        GROUP BY P.Code, P.StartDate, P.EndDate, P.UpdatedOn) PInfo ON Customers.Code = PInfo.Code
    WHERE 
      (ISNULL(Customers.TransDate, Customers.UpdatedOn) >= PInfo.StartDate AND ISNULL(Customers.TransDate, Customers.UpdatedOn) <= PInfo.EndDate AND Customers.UpdatedOn < PInfo.UpdatedOn)
        AND Customers.DeletedOn IS NULL

END
```

If I run the above procedure, then run the following commands:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CustomerID)) FROM ReCalc
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID)) FROM ReCalc
```

The second result is approximately twice as big as the first result.

I cannot determine what is wrong with my query that is resulting in so many duplicate customers being added when they do not need to actually be recalculated.

Comment: You obviously have customer with more than one record in `PaymentPlan` that satisfies the conditions. Do you want to include a customer as soon as at least one record in `PaymentPlan` satisfies the conditions? What if there are 2 that do, 2 that don't for the same customer.... Do you want to include that customer?

Comment: @trincot `Customer` isn't in or tied to `PaymentPlan` in any way. PP just contains those two fields (its "effective date range") and some modifiers to apply to a transaction. The dates cannot overlap (though UpdatedOn could be any date as you can go back and change older plans). `CustomerID` is unique, as it is a PK in the `Customers` table. The `CustomerID` should be inserted into the Recalc table exactly once, as soon as we've determined its `TransDate` or `UpdatedOn` is within the effective date range AND `C.Upodated` On < `PP.UpdatedOn`

Comment: CustomerID is unique in the Customers table, but its Code as it is appearing in PaymentPlan is not unique in that second table.

Comment: *"Customer isn't in or tied to PaymentPlan in any way. "*: your join condition suggests otherwise: `Customers.Code = PInfo.Code`.

Comment: So why not just add a `GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID` after the last WHERE clause?

Comment: The `Code` column refers to a "group" of `Customers`. For example, if you ran `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Code = XYZ` you would and should get multiple records. Different groups will use different `PaymentPlan` records. So one group might have a PP ranging from 10/1/2000 - 11/1/200, whereas another group might have PP ranging from 10/1/2000 - 10/15/2000 and 10/16/2000 - 11/1/2000. We want to ensure we're using the correct PP data for the right Customer, based off their Code column.

Comment: I wonder if you really do not have overlapping periods. Try this for testing that: `select p1.code, p1.StartDate from PaymentPlan p1 inner join PaymentPlan p2 on p1.code = p2.code and p1.StartDate between p2.StartDate and p2.EndDate`. If you are right, this should return 0 records. If more: there is your explanation of the duplicates.

Comment: @trincot Ack; looks like it could in fact be a problem with bad, old test data in the PP table. Thanks.

Comment: I will post that as an answer then ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicates are caused by the data in the `PaymentPlan` table. Although the intention is that the periods defined in that table are non-overlapping for a given `Code`, this probably is not the case, and would explain for the duplicates.

To identify if indeed you have such overlapping periods in the `PaymentPlan` table, issue this statement:

```
select     p1.code, p1.StartDate
from       PaymentPlan p1
inner join PaymentPlan p2
        on p1.code = p2.code
       and p1.StartDate between p2.StartDate and p2.EndDate
```

If this query returns records, then that explains the duplicates. The returned records will give you a clue where to look for such inconsistencies in the `PaymentPlan` table.

Once you have resolved those, you will no longer produce duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking back to `Customers` in the inner query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @aDaysBack = @aDaysBack * -1; -- Since we're looking "back" in time, we want the negative value of the number passed to the procedure

INSERT INTO ReCalc (CustomerID, InsertedOn, RecordStatus, ProcessedOn)

SELECT CustomerID, GETDATE(), 0, null 
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT P.Code, P.StartDate, P.EndDate
    FROM PaymentPlan P 
    INNER JOIN 
      Customers c2 ON c2.Code = p.Code
                  AND c2.UpdatedOn < p.UpdatedOn
                  AND c2.DeletedOn IS NULL
    WHERE P.UpdatedOn >= DATEADD(day, @aDaysBack, GETDATE()) 
    AND   P.DeletedOn IS NULL
    GROUP BY P.Code, P.StartDate, P.EndDate
) 
PInfo 
ON  Customers.Code = PInfo.Code
AND ISNULL(Customers.TransDate, Customers.UpdatedOn) 
     BETWEEN PInfo.StartDate AND PInfo.EndDate
```